# Unable to install Laravel via Composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, fedora-23

I'm getting an error while trying to install Laravel using Composer. I also had the same problem trying to install composer itself, was getting "Connection Timed-out", so I had to download composer.phar manually. I'm using Fedora 23. Here's my input:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel project
```

and the error i'm getting:

```
    [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                             
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
```

My internet is working fine and I'm not using proxy. What could be the issue?
Thanks.

Comment: `wget https://packagist.org/packages.json`, does it work?

Comment: Maybe check if Bash is behind your firewall?

Comment: Still no luck, still timing out: `--2017-01-05 17:56:30--  https://packagist.org/packages.json
Connecting to 172.16.1.55:8080... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.`

Comment: We don't have a firewall @shalvah Plus i'm still able to download stuff.

Comment: @Mathenge take a look at this GitHub issue. Hope it helps. https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4388

Answer (score 0):

Try locating the cacert.pem file(console: `locate cacert.pem`) and add this to your php.ini

```
openssl.cafile= the cacert.pem path
```

so for example the path is `/usr/local/share/perl5/Mozilla/CA/cacert.pem` then add the following line to your php.ini

```
openssl.cafile=/usr/local/share/perl5/Mozilla/CA/cacert.pem;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion @Jesse de gans. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I'm extremely sorry for wasting your time guys. I realized I'm the one who was wrong. A few days ago I was working somewhere and I was required to change my proxy settings. Now my browser was still working fine when I got back but any download from the terminal was timing out. Just changed proxy to "None" and everything is working fine. Thank you very much for your suggestions. I appreciate.